# What does John McWhorter intend to say by 'internal surmise'?

Tags: terminology

John McWhorter [PhD Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter).  [*Words on the Move* (2016)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1627794719). [p. 105 Bottom.](https://books.google.coma/books?id=vKqTCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA73&ots=2xIbBLOtDF&dq=%22it's%20easy%20to%20see%20how%20one%20gets%20from%20yelling%20to%20crying%22&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> We have already seen that there is a theme of weakening signals in how 
>   words 
>   move through time. The firmly objective meaning becomes more elusively subjective: the command of *You must be up by seven o’clock* becomes the **internal surmise** of *That must be the woman I saw the other day*.

What does the emboldened noun phrase signify? I emailed McWhorter several times, but haven't heard back.

BTW, I don't have the book with me. If more context helps, please LMK, and I'll reborrow it.

Comment: There is parallelism here between the two parts of the sentence. 'Objective vs. subjective' parallels 'command' vs. 'surmise'. You should consult the definitions of 'internal' and 'surmise'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

McWhorter is talking about the semantic shift of modals like *must*.

In its strong sense, "must" signifies obligation: "You must be up by 7" means "You are required to be up by 7."

In its weak sense, "must" signifies the conclusion of some reasoning. "That must be her" means "The evidence leads me to conclude that that is her."

Hence the "command" becoming a "surmise", i.e. a reflection or speculation.

There are also ambiguous cases, like "The technology must be highly accessible." Is this a design specification being stated, or is it a conclusion based on seeing some feature it has?

Whether this particular classification of "strong" and "weak" is coherent is not clear to me, but whether the chronology he proposes is true can likely be verified using the OED, which lists senses chronologically.

Comment: I sure hope it's not common to call these "strong" and "weak", they're extremely poor labels when we already such have excellent clear terms: deontic and epistemic modality.